# Is there a resource/server that times out for testing?

Tags: php, http, timeout

I'm trying to recreate a problem that occurs when the source of file_get_contents times out. I'm attempting to write some PHP to check for this and display an error message within the site when this happens, rather than the default which is a full page error no allowing you to use the rest of the site functionality.

I have tried setting the timeout limit and using sleep, returning the header as a timeout status code but neither will replicate the issue.

Is there a resource on the internet which is set up for testing or is there a better way to replicate it?

Comment: You can pass a 'context' to `file_get_contents` that contains a timeout setting in seconds. If you pass a very small value, you will always/often get timeout conditions. Better still, if you can point to a custom PHP script, use this feature together with a `sleep` in the URL target, and you'll have something to test against.

Comment: This worked thanks. If you make as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) with a 'context' value to specify a timeout setting. You create a context resource with [stream_context_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), which permits the specification of various stream/file options, as detailed [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php).

For timeout, you'll want to set "[http](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)" options, in particular the "timeout" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a windows box, then fiddler2 http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ would be a good start. Fiddler2 can be easily scripted and it can create any kind of timeout condition you want.
You might want to start here: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp

Comment: Unfortunately using an Ubuntu VM on a Mac but thanks for your response.